# In a GWT HTML widget displaying complex HTML, how do I add an event handler for specific subelements?

Tags: gwt

I'm optimizing a GWT application that previously used a variety of nested panels to work with DIVs and Spans. I generate the entire table as a single SafeHtml object and then assigning it into a single SafeHtml widget.

I now want to be able to track mouseover/mouseout events at the level of the specific 'cell' spans rather than the entire table, but I'm not sure how to do this.

If I add a handler to the HTML widget itself, I'll get events sourced at various elements.

Answer (score 7):

Since 2.0 there is quite a simple way to do it. 
For example if you HTML code is contained in some kind of widget (HTMLPanel or HTML), you can call`addDomHandler(<handler>,<eventtyoe>)` on that widget, so you will receive events from inner html. 
For example if you have a bunch of anchors inside HTMLPanel and you want to know which one was clicked you can do something like this:

```
panel.addDomHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            Element element=  event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget().cast();
            if(element.getTagName().equals("A")) {
                AnchorElement anchor = element.cast();
                Window.alert("Anchor with href " + anchor.getHref() + " was clicked");
            }

        }
    }, ClickEvent.getType());
```

Since you want to track mouseover/out events you will have to use 2 different dom handlers, find out cell you need when event is fired and then change its state.

Answer (score -1):

The way to approach this is:

- Find the element you need with one of the DOM methods, like `DOM.getElementById(..)` or any other means. View `Widget.getElement()` etc.
- Call `DOOM.sinkEvents(element,eventBits)` or `DOM.sinkBitlessEvent(element,eventName)` and pass the required events you want to sink in form of a bitmask, like `Event.MOUSEEVENTS` or using a named event like `click` or `touchstart` if using the second method.
- set and EventListener on the element, by calling `DOM.setEventListerner(element,eventListener)` like so:

  ```
  DOM.setEventListener( element, new EventListener()
  {

      @Override
      public void onBrowserEvent( Event event )
      {
          if ("click".event.getType()) {
             // ..do stuff..
          }
      }
  } );
  ```

Only events you've specified in step 2 will be fired to your EventListener, so you need to only handle those.

Comment: This is too prone to memory leaks (at least in IE). You have to make sure you setElementListener to null to avoid leaks; which is what widgets are for. See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/DomEventsAndMemoryLeaks